# Society without money

Tags: society, economy

What are the ways in which resources can be distributed in the society other than the use of money or the barter system, so that unequal or unfair distribution of resources can be avoided? If a society like that were to exist, how would it function (with technological development like the one we have now)?

Comment: This _way_ too broad for this Q&A. You need to narrow it down, such as giving some information about what kind of society you're talking about, technological level, if it's an earth-like or other kind of world etc. - without these, this could just as well have been asked on history.SE or requires writing a book on economics. Not to mention that people can have all kinds of opinions - leaving it open will invite a bit too much speculation.

Comment: OT: I misread "Society without monkey"

Comment: For starting ideas you can read "Voyage from Yesteryear" by James P Hogan, this novel has a post-scarcity society interacting with a more conventional one as its core.

Comment: You can also look at the Culture books by Ian M Banks and at Star Trek for more examples of post-scarcity economies.

Comment: Look up "gift economy", "communism", and "post-scarcity economy" as starting points.

Comment: One critical question is how much there is to go around. Are you trying to distribute contested resources in a state of scarcity? Is there just about enough to go around as long as people share? Or are you imagining a post-scarcity world in which there's plenty for everybody, and the only big problem is preventing the powerful from sucking up so many of resources that they leave everyone else starving and beholden to them?

Comment: Star Trek have replicators which pretty much solves all [economic problems](http://www.digitopoly.org/2013/11/19/that-star-trek-economy-thing/). but i don't think it is possible in society with current technological state like ours.

Comment: Ursula LeGuin's book *The Dispossessed* also deals ably with this question. It contrasts a capitalistic society with the semi-anarchist society that tore off from it. In this case, she emphasizes culture and education, and the people whose job it is to oversee distribution only come into play during famines.

Comment: @user93 Actually we've plenty of ability to do that with our current tech level. Things are already heading in that direction although unfortunately the gap between rich and poor is still growing faster than the poor are getting less poor.

Comment: Lol I found a fun comment, tried to upvote it, didn't work, then noticed it was _mine_. And it's not the first time this happens!